# HP Proliant DL120 with 3rd party 4Tb drives not showing full capacity

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

We've purchased a HP Proliant DL120 G7, which has an onboard Smart Array B110i controller. In the server, we've bought 4 x Hitachi 4Tb SATA drives, mounted them in HP drive caddies and installed them in the server. However, the B110i controller only shows the drives as 1.8Tb:

[image]

If we disable the B110i and use the AHCI controller instead, all 4Tb per drive is available. We'd really like to use the B110i if possible; does anyone know why the full drive capacity isn't available? According to the [QuickSpecs](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14009_div/14009_div.pdf), 4Tb drives are supported (and yes, I realise these aren't **HP** drives).

Comment: And *that's* why pro's buy supported hardware combinations!

Comment: recent RAID controller firmware is installed?

Comment: @Chopper3: and that's why I'm asking here rather than directly to HP; I'll hand my "pro" badge back in immediately.

Comment: @Striker_84: yes, tried bumping all the firmwares, everything's up to date :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I swear, when I read questions like this, I wonder why people are even using 4TB disks in inexpensive servers with low-end controllers. Do you *really* need 8TB-12TB usable in a *four* disk setup? What are you storing?!?

Either way, the Smart Array B110i controller is not compatible with drives larger than 2TB in RAID. It's not well-documented or noted online, but you've run into a product limitation. Remember, this controller predates the introduction of 4TB disks by a bit.

If you need to use *those* specific 3rd party disks, then you're going to have to swap controllers or use software RAID.

Comment: OK - this server is/was going to be a dumping ground for very infrequently-accessed, very unimportant but very large data that needs to be kept online. It was either that or a NAS, and re-using the server was a cheap (and according to the HP documentation, ***viable*** option). In no way was this designed to "cut corners", just trying to re-use hardware in a manner that the manufacturer suggests is possible! I wonder what would happen if we'd bought 4TB HP disks ...

Comment: Possibly the same thing. The drives are supported with a Smart Array P410 controller.

Comment: OK, thanks. We can use the AHCI mode; not as nice, but again this isn't anything "production" level. And the QuickSpecs are **very** deceiving - 4TB drives are listed as an option, with NO mention that the B110i won't support them.

Comment: HP was *very shady* on this one. The controller is intentionally crippled and really part of the motherboard's BIOS. Earlier revisions of the embedded controller on G6 servers shows ">2TB drives not supported".

Answer (score -2):

HP B110i Controller only support drives up to 2TB. Its written in the HP Bulletin.

Comment: show us the document