# Smart Array B110i SATA RAID failure. Raid volume broken

Tags: windows-server-2003

I was troubleshooting our server backup when I discovered 2 newly listed drives from within windows explorer.  We previously had 1 logical drive, (3 drives; 2 mirrored & 1 hot spare, configured as a raid volume.)  This volume has been solid; running great for 5 years. Last week I shut the system down and installed additional ram to the system; the server appeared to have loaded without errors and was unaware of the raid controller failure.  The server OS has loaded from one of the raid member drives.  My question is; how bad will this be if the system restarts?  Obviously I'm going to get right on fixing the backup, but am very unsure as to what I'll need to do in order to get my raid protection back with little as possible effort. Will I need to reinstall?

Comment: If the raid controller fails - how can you SEE the drives? Or is this one of those "fake" controllers that are glorified drivers?

Comment: That RAID controller has an option in its BIOS to disable it and use it as a regular AHCI controller [see here](http://serverfault.com/questions/538030/hp-proliant-dl120-with-3rd-party-4tb-drives-not-showing-full-capacity), if the BIOS got reset and the controller disabled while you were in the guts, that *might* explain seeing all 3 drives now.  I have no idea what would happen if you rebooted and enabled the RAID again, especially since the drive you're using now will be different from the other.

Comment: I'm not going to try re-enabling raid on these drives. Contacted HP and they say they'd come replace the system mainboard for free; which is great, but I'm really not interested in reinstalling everything (we have an accpac accounting system that was very difficult configure; would cost major $$ of support to install again).  I had thoughts of shutting the system down, removing all drives; add\configure three new drives in the raid controller, followed by ghosting the last production drive onto the new logical raid drive.  Only problem is if we put new board in; is windows going to freak out?

Comment: I know windows would require 'repair' if I was replacing the mainboard with something completely different; but this will be the exact same board.  Anyone had any experiences with this?  I'm tempted to skip the mainboard replace and see if the raid controller comes back for re-configure on reboot; all to avoid reinstalling everything.